# How to set items to 0 in cart

Tags: flutter

I have a bug and I don't see where is the problem.

Context -> I have created a method so the user can increase and decrease the items in the card by pressing a button or by adding the number manually.

The problem comes when the user modifies the number of items manually.

This is the method:

```
 Future<void> setProductQuantity({
    @required Product product,
    @required String cartId,
    @required int quantity,
  }) async {
    Cart cart = getCart(cartId) ?? _createCart(cartId: cartId, products: [product]);
    Product productInCart = cart.getProductForId(product.id);

    if (productInCart != null) {
      if (quantity == 0) {
        cart.products.remove(productInCart);
      } else {
        productInCart.quantity = quantity;
      }
    } else {
      product.quantity = quantity;
      cart.products.add(product);
    }
    await persistCart(cart);
  }
```

The problem is if one of the items is more than 0 and the rest are 0, the items with 0 quantity gets added as well to the card. I would like to avoid that to happen.

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the else condition check for the quantity and add it to the cart only if it's higher than 0. That way you any item with quality 0 will not be added to the cart.